# ActivityNotFoundException after queryIntents.size > 0 for Calendar App

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a Intent for the Calendar app and was reporting runtimeexception with activitynotfound. The solution was to add queryIntents before start Activity, but it is still reporting the same error and it is resolving to true in the if in the new app version.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
            .setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, date)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, date)
            .putExtra(Events.TITLE, title)
            .putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, description)
            .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, adress)
            .putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY);
    if(getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0).size() > 0)
        startActivity(intent);
    else
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Warn")
                .setMessage("No app on device to handle")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new FinishOnClickListener(this));
```

And the error is still raised from startActivity.

How to check properly or try/catch the Exception is the only solution?

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult (Instrumentation.java:1793)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity (Instrumentation.java:1491)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult (Activity.java:3796)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult (Activity.java:3744)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivity (Activity.java:4067)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivity (Activity.java:4035)
  at br.CalendarLocalActivity.onCreate (CalendarLocalActivity.java:44)
```

Where line 44 is startActivity.

Also, the code above is at onCreate of the Activity.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the Java stack trace?

Comment: Added, the exception message is not visible on GooglePlay console anymore

Comment: Hmmm... usually that exception spells out the `Intent` details, which is what I was looking for. My guess, given your comment, is that you cannot reproduce the problem but are working solely off of crash logs from the field. If so... I guess that `try`/`catch` is your best bet. You could try `resolveActivity()` instead of `queryIntentActivites()` and check for a `null` response, but I don't know if that will get you past the problem.